# Install npm and node on Homestead

Tags: node.js, laravel, laravel-5, npm, homestead

I am new to Laravel framework, a day before I wanted to install a package using **npm** for my project on Homestead, but I had some problems when I run `sudo npm install` , I spent too much time to figure out what was the problem, and I ended up by removing **npm** and **node** from Homestead! (by mistake). Now I don't know how to reinstall them in my **virtual machine** (in Homestead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It already comes with node.js (and npm by extend):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead

> Included Software
>
> - Ubuntu 16.04
> - Git
> - PHP 7.1
> - Nginx
> - MySQL
> - MariaDB
> - Sqlite3
> - PostgreSQL
> - Composer
> - **Node (With Yarn, Bower, Grunt, and Gulp)**
> - Redis
> - Memcached
> - Beanstalkd
> - Mailhog
> - ngrok

So the best way to go is probably just create a new homestead instance

Comment: Is there any other solution than creating a new instance? To reinstall node and npm?

Comment: I just find how to upgrade node and npm on Homestead, but couldn't find how to install it.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Comment: Thank you, I ended up by getting a new homestead instance, as I had some problems installing node, and that would consume some more time to fix them.

Comment: If this is the intended answer, you should accept it on the left under the score